# How do I create a progress bar in html5, javascript or php?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, progress-bar

I already have this code, however instead of the numerical upload progess, what i want is a graphical bar...i also noticed a problem here...the progressNumber only shows if I click on submit even without choosing a file..but if a choose a file, the progressNumber doesn't show..

```
      <script type="text/javascript">



function fileSelected() {




        var file = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[0];
        if (file) {
          var fileSize = 0;
          if (file.size > 1024 * 1024)
            fileSize = (Math.round(file.size * 100 / (1024 * 1024)) / 100).toString() + 'MB';

          else
            fileSize = (Math.round(file.size * 100 / 1024) / 100).toString() + 'KB';

          document.getElementById('fileName').innerHTML = 'Name: ' + file.name;
          document.getElementById('fileSize').innerHTML = 'Size: ' + fileSize;
         // document.getElementById('fileType').innerHTML = 'Type: ' + file.type;
        }
      }

      function uploadFile() {





        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append("fileToUpload", document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[0]);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false);
      xhr.open("POST", "thankyou.php");
      xhr.send(fd);

return false;
      }

      function uploadProgress(evt) {





       if (evt.lengthComputable) {
          var percentComplete = Math.round(evt.loaded * 100 / evt.total);




         document.getElementById('progressNumber').innerHTML = percentComplete.toString() + ' % uploading file';

         document.getElementById('progress').style.width = percentComplete + '%';


        }
        else {
          document.getElementById('progressNumber').innerHTML = 'unable to compute';
        }
      }

      function uploadComplete(evt) {
        /* This event is raised when the server send back a response */
       // alert(evt.target.responseText);
      }

      function uploadFailed(evt) {
        alert("There was an error attempting to upload the file.");
      }

      function uploadCanceled(evt) {
     //   alert("The upload has been canceled by the user or the browser dropped the connection.");
      }

 </script>
```

and for the html form and input tag

```
<form id="form1" name = "myform"  onsubmit = "return uploadFile()" enctype="multipart/form-data" action = "thankyou.php"  method="post"  id = "form1" >



<div class="row">
      <label for="fileToUpload">Upload File</label>
      <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" onchange="fileSelected();" class = "dropzone" required/>
    </div>
<p>

    <div id="fileName"></div>
    <div id="fileSize"></div>
    <div id="fileType"></div>
<div id="progressNumber"></div>


<div id="progress-bg" style="width:200px;height:10px;background:#FFF">
    <div id="progress" style="height:10px;background:#000"></div>
</div>

    <input type="submit"  name="uploadFiles" value="Submit">
```

Answer (score 0):

There is special tag in HTML5:

```
<progress value="0.25" id="progressNumber">25%</progress>
```

The "25%" will only be shown in browsers which do not support the progress tag. You can also use another syntax:

```
<progress value="25" max="100">25 out of 100</progress>
```

In you case you might use the first syntax and change the line

```
document.getElementById('progressNumber').innerHTML = percentComplete.toString() + ' % uploading file';
```

to lines

```
document.getElementById('progressNumber').innerHTML = percentComplete.toString() + ' % uploading file';
document.getElementById('progressNumber').value = evt.loaded/evt.total;
```

Comment: instead of the value being 25, can the value be the percentage of the file being uploaded? I tried adding this to the form..but the bar does not seem to update

`code`
<progress id='p'></progress>


var p = document.getElementById('p');
// 'reader' is of type FileReader
reader.addEventListener('loadstart', function(evt) {
  if (evt.lengthComputable) p.max = evt.total;
}, false);
reader.addEventListener('progress', function(evt) {
  if (evt.lengthComputable) p.value = evt.loaded;
}, false);

</script>
`code`

Comment: @Rexcel if you don't specify property "max", the value should be between 0 and 1. Call it percentage or whatever you want. Your code seems alright... Does the listeners themselves work? Can you make them update anything in the page?

Comment: i found out something interesting..the visual progress bar works if I change to button: <input type = "button">..instead of <input type = "submit"> , however if i change the input type to button after submitting the file, it does not proceed to thankyou.php anymore as defined in the form action..it just stays on the same page

Comment: It might be that by submitting the form gets "closed" and not updated anymore. Do you want to forward user to that thankyou.php? You could redirect him with javascript when the upload is finished. Otherwise it makes no sense to redirect him AND show him the upload bar in the previous page...

Comment: The HTML5 progress element is not widely supported - http://caniuse.com/#feat=progressmeter - see my answer for a cross browser solution

Comment: @Ali Gangji: same problem as above..the progress bar works if the input type = button..but if i change the input tyoe to submit...the progress bar doesn't work anymore =(

Answer (score 0):

Create the progress bar background or container with a fixed width and put the progress bar div inside it:

```
<div id="progress-bg" style="width:200px;height:10px;background:#FFF">
    <div id="progress" style="height:10px;background:#000"></div>
</div>
```

on the progress event, simply set the width of the progress bar to the percentage completed.

```
document.getElementById('progress').style.width = percentComplete + '%';
```

Comment: You don't need to call `.toString()` on an number.

Comment: @Ali Gangji: same problem as above..the progress bar works if the input type = button..but if i change the input tyoe to submit...the progress bar doesn't work anymore =(

Comment: don't put a click handler on the submit button. Put `onsubmit="return uploadFile()"` on the form tag. `return false` at the end of your uploadFile() function.

Comment: i ommitted the clickhandler on submit button, changed the input tyoe to submit instead of button...and added an onsubmit handler on the form tag..the progress bar already works..however, once the progress bar is finished, it does not proceed to thankyou.php anymore...

Comment: edited  my question above (as of Tue 2:21 PM GMT +8)..so the code suits the necessary changes you suggested =)

Comment: your `uploadComplete` function needs to handle redirecting the user. You can use something like `window.location.href = 'http://'+window.location.host+'/thankyou.php';`